# scenekit physics simulations vary drastically on different phones

Tags: ios, scenekit

I was playing around with SceneKit. I noticed that physics simulations on various iPhones look completely different. For example: I used a box physics body, applied a force on it to make it spin and hit in on the SCNFloor with gravity. 2 devices, same code, completely different physics. Is that normal and what can I do about it?

Comment: Curious as to what you observed as "completely different"? eg; on one device the box bounced left, and on the other right. Or on one device the box bounces, and on the other it falls through the floor. I'd expect the former behaviour, and I'd even expect to see the same code/device produce different results. But I've also seen the latter, which concerns me a little more.

Comment: On one device goes left, on other right. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: You could try to bias the simulation a little more, so that instead of dropping the box on its edge or flat, angle it in the direction you want it to bounce. Apart from that you're at the mercy of floating point maths...

Comment: What about other game engines or frameworks. Do you have any experience with how they handle physics?

Answer (score 0):

Physics in the iOS game engines don't use delta timing, instead subjecting themselves to the whimsy of the OS and the CPU/GPU's ability to deal with those whimsies.

As a consequence, there's almost never any kind of surety with regards the result/nature of physical interactions anywhere near 60fps in terms of needs.

Figure out a way to use delta time with their physics engines and this should be somewhat resolved, but nowhere near entirely.

Comment: One could use renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) to get the delta time between calls to this function. Not sure how to use that information though :)

Comment: The `SCNPhysicsWorld` object controls all physics interactions in a scene, it has a property [`timeStep`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsWorld_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPhysicsWorld/timeStep) that defaults to 60Hz (60fps). Not debating that there is some uncertainty, as I've seen some 'weird' stuff, just that according to the docs it may not be timestep related.